# Application running triggers another application installation

Tags: android

My application is a trial version apk. Once the period is completed, can I initiate another application to be installed/downloaded from the android market ( purchasing process) which is a paid application using the current running trail application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best you can do is point the user to your appication in the market by searching for it:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.example.yourpackage")));
```

Comment: Can the second application be hidden and not exposed to users in android market....